# Variable floating point variable conditional Gforth

Tags: forth, gforth

To expand this, how can I do this with variables?

```
 fvariable foo 6.2e foo f!
 fvariable boo 8.2e boo f!

 boo @ foo @ f> // How is this done?
```

Comment: Float literals should be represented in [exponential form](https://forth-standard.org/standard/float#subsection.12.3.6) (scientific notation), it should contain `e` term: `6.2e`, `8.2e`, or `0.28e1`.

Comment: Yes you're right. Edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access floating point variables with `f@` and `f!`.

```
boo f@ foo f@ f>
```